# Redundant array for creating a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I've following array of `ids`

```
$ids = array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '2',
  2 => '2',
  3 => '2',
  4 => '1',
);
```

and array of `value_ids`

```
$value_ids = array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '13',
  2 => '',
  3 => '13',
  4 => '5',
);
```

and I want the following output

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => '5',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '13',
  ),
);
```

And I've used

```
$kma_manager_ids = $data_dump = []; // saving combination array data of KMA ID and same Manager ID
foreach ($kma_ids as $k => $v) {
    $data_dump[$v][] = $manager_ids[$k];
}
array_walk($data_dump,function($v,$k) use (&$kma_manager_ids){
    $kma_manager_ids[$k] = array_unique(array_filter($v));
});
```

and I got the following output but it seems its not the perfect way to use  `foreach` and `array_walk` at the same time is there any other way to achieve the following output

Comment: Can you give the logic how the array to be designed?

Comment: I think I've  already given

Comment: I did't catch from the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have not done a great job of explaining the required logic for your task so I assumed the required logic by working backward from the desired result.

This task can be performed with one loop as long as you access the second array's elements by the index from the first array while looping.

The first level keys are determined by the value in the `$ids` array.

The second level has keys which are incremented from zero for each occurrence of the id.

If the cached value is empty, then it should be overwritten by the next occurring value relating to that id.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lqhlH))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($ids as $i => $id) {
    $counter[$id] = ($counter[$id] ?? -1) + 1;
    if (!isset($result[$id]) || !current($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id] = [$counter[$id] => $value_ids[$i]];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```